# How to create new table of XML type by fetching data from another table in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is a sample table named 'CARS', which is just part of a much larger table.

```
MODEL              ID

Ferrari             1
Mustang             2
Taurus              3
```

I want make a new table say named CARS_XML, changing each row from CARS into a single XML type 
column, using a cursor to fetch the data from the table CARS (instead of inserting the values of each row) to form new table CARS_XML.  The resulting table has XML tags of `CAR`, `MODEL` and `ID` with the values of the the first table `CARS` inserted in the correct place within the XML tags so that the select * from CARS_XML would read like below:

```
< CAR>< MODEL>Ferrari< /MODEL>< ID>1< /ID>< /MODEL>< /CAR>
< CAR>< MODEL>Mustang< /MODEL>< ID>2< /ID>< /MODEL><  /CAR>
< CAR>< MODEL>Taurus< /MODEL>< ID>3< /ID>< /MODEL>< /CAR>
```

To start off with, do I declare a `sys.xmltype` and define it and if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Why you want to put your `xml` in another table,instead of that generate `xml` on fly from `CARS` table whenever required.

The reason why i am saying this because `CARS` table have constraints from another table.Which you need to duplicate on that CAR_XML in order to maintain the consistency.

Another reason is that whenever you inserted data into `CARS` table ,you need to insert the same into `CAR_XML`.So write a function which  get the data from `CARS` table on FLY.
If not ,create a trigger on CARS table ,On `insert update delete` ,it do the same on `CAR_XML` table.

```
create table cars(model varchar2(200),id number);
insert into cars values('Ferrari',1);
insert into cars values('Mustang',2);
insert into cars values('Taurus',3);


SELECT XMLElement("CAR", 
                        XMLElement("MODEL",c.model) ,
                        XMLElement("ID", c.id)
                 ) AS "RESULT" 
FROM cars c;
```

*OUTPUT*

```
< CAR>< MODEL>Ferrari< /MODEL>< ID>1< /ID>< /MODEL>< /CAR>
< CAR>< MODEL>Mustang< /MODEL>< ID>2< /ID>< /MODEL><  /CAR>
< CAR>< MODEL>Taurus< /MODEL>< ID>3< /ID>< /MODEL>< /CAR>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the script below will do what you are looking for, although I can't check it fully. However what you are trying to do seems to be problematic. Presumably at some point in the future you are going to send this xml somewhere, to me, the best time to convert your data to xml would be when you want to send it, rather than leaving it in a table, taking up space in your database. You also now have the same data in 2 different places, usually a bad thing in database design.

```
CREATE TABLE cars
(model varchar2(30)
,id   number(3));

INSERT INTO cars
(model
,id)
VALUES ( 'Ferrari',1);

INSERT INTO cars
(model
,id)
VALUES ( 'Mustang',2);


INSERT INTO cars
(model
,id)
VALUES ( 'Taurus',3);

CREATE TABLE cars_xml
(xml_data xmltype);


INSERT INTO cars_xml
SELECT xmlelement("CAR",xmlelement("MODEL",c.model)||xmlelement("ID",c.id))
FROM cars c;
```

Comment: +1 You can test your code with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a1ee/7), although it seems to have some trouble displaying XMLTypes without `getStringVal()`.